# Converting $3t\cos t\sin3t+2\cos t\cos3t-t\sin t\cos3t-6\cos^2t$ to $4\cos^2t\; ( t\sin2t+\cos2t-2)$

Tags: trigonometry

How to alignment.
$$f(t)=3t \cos(t)\sin(3t)+2\cos(t)\cos(3t)-t\sin(t)\cos(3t)-6\cos^2(t)$$
are alternate forms
$$f(t)=4 \cos^2(t)\; ( t \sin(2 t)+ \cos(2 t)-2)$$
Please show me the steps.

Comment: The obvious difference is the $3t$ and the $2t$. So start by breaking them up using sum identities, $\cos(3t)=\cos(2t+t)=...$

Answer (score 0):

First, we can use the angle addition identities:

$$\sin(\theta + \phi) = \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) + \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$$

$$\cos(\theta + \phi) = \cos(\theta)\cos(\phi) - \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$$

From this, we get:

$$\sin(3\theta) = \sin(2\theta + \theta) = \sin(2\theta)\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta)\cos(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos^{2}(\theta) + \sin(\theta)\cos^{2}(\theta) - \sin^{3}(\theta)$$

$$\cos(3\theta) = \cos(2\theta + \theta) = \cos(2\theta)\cos(\theta) - \sin(2\theta)\sin(\theta) = \cos^{3}(\theta) - \sin^{2}(\theta)\cos(\theta) - 2\sin^{2}(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$

$$\sin(3\theta) = 3\sin(\theta)\cos^{2}(\theta) - \sin^{3}(\theta)$$

$$\cos(3\theta) = \cos^{3}(\theta) - 3\sin^{2}(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$

(In deriving these, we use the double angle identities $\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta) = \cos^{2}(\theta) - \sin^{2}(\theta)$, which can be found in the same way.) Can you take it from here?

If you're still stuck:

> Using the triple-angle identities:
>
>  $$f(t) = 3t\cos(t)\sin(3t) + 2\cos(t)\cos(3t) - t\sin(t)\cos(3t) - 6\cos^{2}(t)$$
>
>  $$f(t) = 9t\sin(t)\cos^{3}(t) - 3t\sin^{3}(t)\cos(t) + 2\cos^{4}(t) - 6\sin^{2}(t)\cos^{2}(t) - t\sin(t)\cos^{3}(t) + 3t\sin^{3}(t)\cos(t) - 6\cos^{2}(t)$$
>
>  $$f(t) =8t\sin(t)\cos^{3}(t) + 2\cos^{4}(t)- 6\sin^{2}(t)\cos^{2}(t) - 6\cos^{2}(t)$$
>
>  Using $\sin^{2}(t) = 1-\cos^{2}(t)$:
>
>  $$f(t) = 8t\sin(t)\cos^{3}(t) + 2\cos^{4}(t) - 6(1-\cos^{2}(t))\cos^{2}(t) - 6\cos^{2}(t)$$
>
>  $$f(t) = 8t\sin(t)\cos^{3}(t) + 8\cos^{4}(t) - 12\cos^{2}(t)$$
>
>  $$f(t) = 4\cos^{2}(t)(2t\sin(t)\cos(t) + 2\cos^{2}(t) - 3)$$
>
>  Using $\cos^{2}(t) = 1-\sin^{2}(t)$:
>
>  $$f(t) = 4\cos^{2}(t)(2t\sin(t)\cos(t) + \cos^{2}(t) - \sin^{2}(t) + 1 - 3)$$
>
>  Using the double angle identities:
>
>  $$\boxed{f(t) = 4\cos^{2}(t)(t\sin(2t) + \cos(2t) - 2)}$$